# Swift - How to group table using object array

Tags: swift, swift2

I have the following class:

```
class ProviderSchedule : AnyObject {

    var providerUid : String = ""
    var lastName : String = ""
    var firstName : String = ""
    var scheduleRegion : String = ""
    var scheduleAmount : Float = 0

    init () {

    }


    }
```

Then I create an array of this object in order to set the source for my UITableView.

```
var tableData : Array<ProviderSchedule> = []
```

My table functions are:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableData.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

What I need is to group my data by:

`lastName` and `firstName` so the name appears on the group section of the table.

> Any clue how to do that?

Comment: providerUid, lastName and firstName are the fields to group by.

Comment: Your question is too complicated to understand. Forget about the word group by, explain it using some other word, or tell us in what order you want to group it.

Comment: You have to use a nested array or a dictionary with backing array for the order. Prepare / populate the arrays while creating the `ProviderSchedule` objects.

Comment: So I need to create arrays besides my object? Any example on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your data to a format that is better suited to a table with groups. Make a class to represent group key, like this:

```
class GroupKey : Hashable {
    let firstName : String
    let lastName : String
    init(fn:String, _ ln:String) {
        firstName = fn
        lastName = ln
    }
    ... // Implement Hashable and Equatable
}
```

Now make an array of `GroupKey` objects, and sort them as desired:

```
var groupSet = Set<GroupKey>()
for s in tableData {
    groupSet.insert(GroupKey(s.firstName, s.lastName))
}
let sortedGroups = Array(groupSet)
sortedGroups.sort {
    $0.firstName < $1.firstName
|| ($0.firstName == $1.firstName && $0.lastName < $1.lastName)
}
```

Prepare schedule groups:

```
var scheduleGroup = [[ProviderSchedule]]()
for g in sortedGroups {
    scheduleGroup.append(
        tableData.filter{$0.firstName == key.firstName && $0.lastName == key.lastName}
    )
}
```

Finally, implement methods supplying section information:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sortedGroups.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return scheduleGroup[section].count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let key = sortedGroups[section]
    return "\(key.lastName), \(key.firstName)"
}
```

Comment: @VAAA Please take a look at the edit. Your code would be a lot more efficient if you also add an array of arrays for each group. It would also make it a lot easier to get to each individual row.

Comment: Got it... let me implement that

Comment: One question, is this ok for the hashable:  //MARK: - Hashable
    var hashValue : Int {
        get {
            return (firstName + " " + lastName).hashValue
        }
    }

Comment: Im getting an error in: sortedGroups.sort  Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions)

Comment: @VAAA I think Xcode can't parse it because it's in the trailing closure form. Try putting parentheses around the curly brace section, or rewrite the closure using the unabbreviated format (i.e. with `in`).

Comment: @VAAA `hashValue` would work slightly better if you use `31*firstName.hashValue+lastName.hashValue` (`31` is a small prime number, this is a well-known trick of combining several hash codes into one).

Comment: it worked partially because now I can see 2 groups but on the table data I always see the same firstname and lastname.

Comment: @VAAA Do you see correct names in the group headers? You need to use `scheduleGroup[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the right schedule.

Comment: Yes I can see the right names in the group headers. Ok let me do that. Appreciate so much your help really!!!!

Comment: Amazing... it was no so easy to do it. Im sure alone I will be here 3 days more trying to figure it out. Appreciate your help.